# UITextfield value for each indexpath.row

Tags: swift

My uitableview consists of 10 cells and each cell has 2 uitextfield's.

I need to take values from each uitextfield in each cell and add it to an array

```
// my custom cell
class MatchTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var Team2Score: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var Team1Score: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var Team2: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var Image2: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var Image1: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var Team1: UILabel!
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}


override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure in the cell initializer for tableviewcontroller that your using your custom cell name and that you've set your identifier correctly. Then just initalize a cell and say something to the effect of

```
cell.Team2Score.text = "100"
```

Comment: no i want to take values written in the text field after running ie. from a user as in the simulator

Answer (score 0):

you will need a global array to hold the strings. So..

```
var wordArray: [String] = []
```

you will need to add a button within the cell so when you hit the button it will add (append in the input of string (letters) to the array.

You need to add a tag to the button to know which cell it was clicked in.

button.tag = indexPath.row

```
@IBaction button(sender: UIButton){

var team2Words = Team2Score.text
wordArray.append(team2Words)    

// do the samething for Team1Score
// you can use and if statement to check if one or the other one is empty

}
```

This will give you a lead

Comment: exactly how to add a tag to the button?
i created the button from the right toolbar